# Swift - collection of Optional objects .first returns double wrapped Optional

Tags: swift

I am struggling to understand why the Array of optionals `.first` returns double wrapped optional in this case and how to avoid it:

```swift
class MyBanana {

}

let bananas = [MyBanana?]()
let first: MyBanana? = bananas.first
```

On the last line i get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'MyBanana??' to specified type 'MyBanana?'

Comment: Imagine if `first` returns `T` instead of `T?` as it currently does. 1) What should `first` return for an empty collection? 2) In the case where `T == MyBanana?` (and so it returns `MyBanana?`), how do you interpret a result of `nil`? Does it mean you have an empty collection, or a collection whose element is `nil`?

Comment: 1) should fatalError 2) element is nil :)

Comment: But i just forgot that is how swift does it, the above is what c# does where there is a distinction between first and firstOrDefault

Comment: If you want that behaviour, then use `array[0]`. But don't, because that's generally shitty. The whole point of the `first`/`last` API is to be able to write code like `guard let first = array.first else { return }`, instead of `if array.isEmpty { return }; let first = array[0] ...`

Comment: Except with [] I cannot do where: block

Comment: The C# API design comes as a consequence of not having an optional type. When you return an optional, you make the `nil` case easily handable by the consumer. They can choose to crash with `!`. They can "OrDefault" it with `?? default`. They could keep the optionality but transform the value with `.map { ... }`, etc. All these choices are available to them through a single `Optional<T>` API, rather than needing duplicate APIs like `foo`, `fooOrDefault`, `bar`, `barOrDefault`, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197018/discussion-between-alexander-and-zaitsman).

Comment: As a side note, do you really need an array of optionals?

Comment: `let first = bananas.first as? MyBanana`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of Optional `MyBanana`s, and `.first` gives you back the first element of the array as an optional.

Calling `.first` on an array is equivalent to this code snippet:

```swift
if array.count == 0 {
    return nil
} else {
    return array[0]
}
```

It's a safe way of getting the first element of an array.

When you call `.first` on an array of type `Array<T>`, you get back an element of type `T?`. `bananas` is of type `Array<MyBanana?>`. Therefore, `T = MyBanana?` and `.first` gives back an element of type `T? = MyBanana??`.

I would strongly recommend you do not keep an array of optional elements, since `.first` already gives you back an optional.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
let first: MyBanana? = bananas.isEmpty ? nil : bananas[0]
```

Although, in my opinion, `first` should handle such a situation without complaining.